# How can one identify the operation to perform in a servlet?

Tags: model-view-controller, servlets, operations, mappings

I am trying to follow this [example](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/guidelines/designing_enterprise_applications_2e/web-tier/web-tier5.html#1078631)
but I can't understand this part: 
`Imagine also that the servlet's context path is myServer/myApp/servlets. The servlet container would direct a request with URL myServer/myApp/createUser.do myServlet to myServlet, because the request URL matches the pattern *.do. Servlet myServlet can extract the requested operation's name from the request URL.`
I can't understand the request, shouldn't it be myServer/myApp/myServlet/createUser.do? And how can one create such a request? Can I just put myServlet/createUser.do in the action of a form?
Thank you for your time.
Iulia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you create a mapping to your servlet for myapp. The servlet name itself usually never shows in the request URL. So every request that goes to myapp will be redirected to your servlet if it matches. That means that your mapping

http://myserver/myapp/*.do

redirects every request with a .do to your servlet. Now the servlet has to deal with the request URL (e.g. render the view for createUser)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've been playing around with it and I've got one question. I'm trying to make the login screen. By default the index.jsp opens:http://localhost:3818/MyApp. I've added this: ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/signin.do at the form's action and this  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> to web.xml. This will not work (makes a submit, gets through, values null). However, if the  web-app is opened with http://localhost:3818/MyApp/signin.do it does work.

Comment: Is there a logical explanation for this - other than "a little red devil came & screwed up my app"-?How can I make the login screen the same as the others? Do I just add the dispatcher as the <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>? Will it suffice?Won't that mean everything will have to go through it? Thank you again for your time.

Comment: I don't really know what you want to do... in fact you don't even say what servlet implementation you are using. You mapping just sais that every call of <whatever>.do will be redirected to your servlet. So Just calling localhost:3818/MyApp simply doesn't redirect because it doesn't have a .do extension (localhost:3818/MyApp/index.do would work though.